# Correct way to construct __in query?

Tags: django

I have two tables as shown below.

```
class AlertTable(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    alarm_text = models.CharField(max_length=800,blank=False,null=False)
    event_type = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class PendingAlertsTable(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    alerttable = models.ForeignKey(AlertTable)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Idea is PendingAlertsTable holds reference to alerts that have not been acknowledged. And AlertTable holds all the alerts.

So I want to construct query such that I can get all entries from AlertTable that are Pending.

So I constructed query like this:

```
inner_qs=PendingAlertsTable.objects.all()
all_pending_event = AlertTable.objects.filter(pk__in=inner_qs)
```

That doesn't give me query set in all_pending_event of expected entries. What is the correct way to construct the __in query in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default that's going to use the id's of the PendingAlertsTable records which are not AlertTable primary keys.

Try this instead:

```
pending_alert_ids = PendingAlertsTable.objects.values_list('alerttable__pk', flat=True).all()
all_pending_event = AlertTable.objects.filter(pk__in=pending_alert_ids)
```

Or better yet, just use `prefetch_related` or `select_related` and do:

```
all_pending_events = [ p.alerttable for p in PendingAlertsTable.objects.prefetch_related('alerttable') ]
```